# using regex on beautiful soup tags

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have been recently using beautiful soup 4 and I have been struggling to understand some basics of this (I was quite ok with bs3.x for some reason). So, for example, lets start off by doing something simple like:

```
data=soup.find_all('h2')
```

which yields me something like:

```
<h2><a href=\"/accurate-data/210-0023.prd?pageLevel=&amp;skuId=210-0023\">more-accurate-data</a></h2>
```

which is fine. But when I want to regex the above string, using something along the lines off (assuming the above is stored in "temp"):

```
t=str(re.compile(r"""<h2><a href=\\"/accurate(.*?)\\">""").search(str(temp)).group(1))
```

I get:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

which I find strange - because, when I do on the python interpretter, something like:

```
k=r"""<h2><a href=\"/accurate-data/210-0023.prd?pageLevel=&amp;skuId=210-0023\">more-accurate-data</a></h2>"""
```

and then use the above regex, everything works fine. I am wondering why the "tags" type generated by bs4 seems non regex'able. Now I feel maybe I am doing something stupid or maybe something has changed between bs3.x and bs4 which I am not aware of. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The fact that you have `<h3>` on your BS4 regex and `<h2>` everywhere else is a typo, right?

Comment: @PedroRomano yes, that was a typo - I am sorry - I have corrected this now.

Comment: Could you show the `repr` of the result given by BS?

Comment: I will get back to you with repr output.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I have figured out what was wrong using the repr ouputs. It was my mistake - I did not know the repr command before. Could you please post that as an answer and I will be glad to accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to see the `repr` of the string:

```
>>> a=r"""<h2><a href=\"/accurate-data/210-0023.prd?pageLevel=&amp;skuId=210-0023\">more-accurate-data</a></h2>"""
>>> print repr(a)
'<h2><a href=\\"/accurate-data/210-0023.prd?pageLevel=&amp;skuId=210-0023\\">more-accurate-data</a></h2>'
```

And the regex works with this representation:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"""<h2><a href=\\"/accurate(.*?)\\">""")
>>> regex.match(a)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x20fbf30>
```

The problem is that the result from beautiful soup is different, because you did not print its repr. When dealing with regexes it's a good idea to check the `repr` of the strings involved to avoid things like this.