# regex + beautifulsoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I've isolated a line of HTML procured from BeautifulSoup that i want to run regex on, but I keep getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'`

I read another stackoverflow question ([using regex on beautiful soup tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010659/using-regex-on-beautiful-soup-tags)) but I can't see what I need to do to fix my version of this issue.

this is my relevant part of the code (url is provided):
**with rob's correct regex update still throwing dat attribute error:**

```
     soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read()).find("div",{"id":"page"})
     addy = soup.find("p","addy").em.encode_contents()
     extracted_entities = re.match(r'\$([\d.]+)\. ([^,]+), ([\d-]+)', addy)
     extracted_entities.groups()
     price = extracted_entities[0]
     location = extracted_entities[1]
     phone = extracted_entities[2]
```

addy seems to be what I want, returning:

```
$10. 2109 W. Chicago Ave., 773-772-0406, <a href="http://www.theoldoaktap.com/">theoldoaktap.com</a>
$9. 800 W. Randolph St., 312-929-4580, <a href="http://aucheval.tumblr.com/">aucheval.tumblr.com</a>
$9.50. 445 N. Clark St., 312-334-3688, <a href="http://www.rickbayless.com/">rickbayless.com</a>
```

and so on, when i print it.

what's going on here? thanks in advance, all.

Comment: Have you tried doing it in two lines like in the example? https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups

Comment: @mrm9084 sry, not seeing what you're referring to really. can you elaborate?

Comment: `\d` is only digits, so "$9.50." won't match that.

Comment: If you try splitting up the line with where you do re.match into two lines, and verify that you are being returned what you want. I am thinking what you are doing will only work on two lines.

Comment: @Rob ah, fudge. oversight. what's your recommendation?

Comment: Think my answer below will match all of your example cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be a stray `"` in your RegEx pattern that I don't see in your example output.

```
match = re.match(r'\$([\d.]+)\. ([^,]+), ([\d-]+)', addy)
if match:
    extracted_entities = match.groups()
else:
    raise Exception("RegEx didn't match '%s'" % addy)
```

Should work:

```
>>> f = """$10. 2109 W. Chicago Ave., 773-772-0406, <a href="http://www.theoldoaktap.com/">theoldoaktap.com</a>
... $9. 800 W. Randolph St., 312-929-4580, <a href="http://aucheval.tumblr.com/">aucheval.tumblr.com</a>
... $9.50. 445 N. Clark St., 312-334-3688, <a href="http://www.rickbayless.com/">rickbayless.com</a>"""
>>> l = f.splitlines()
>>> for i in l:
...   r = re.match(r'\$([\d.]+)\. ([^,]+), ([\d-]+)', i)
...   if r:
...     print "GOT IT", r.groups()
...   else:
...     print "NO GOT IT", i
... 
GOT IT ('10', '2109 W. Chicago Ave.', '773-772-0406')
GOT IT ('9', '800 W. Randolph St.', '312-929-4580')
GOT IT ('9.50', '445 N. Clark St.', '312-334-3688')
```

Comment: This works because although the `[\d.]+` will match "$10." when the parser reaches the literal dot `\.` it will backtrack and force the `+` to match up one fewer character which will allow the overall match to succeed.

Comment: Hey Rob - even with your edits, it's still throwing me the attributeerror nonetype object has no attribute...

for url in sammy_urls:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url).read()).find("div",{"id":"page"})

    addy = soup.find("p","addy").em.encode_contents()

    extracted_entities = re.match(r'\$([\d.]+)\. ([^,]+), ([\d-]+)', addy)

    extracted_entities.groups()

/goddammit how do i indent in comments/

Comment: SpicyClubSauce I think there must be some other line in your data that doesn't match the regex, these are the problems with regex. I do think that @mrm9084 was correct that you should be doing these things on more lines.

Comment: Rob if that's such a common issue w regex, how do ppl parse lines in BeautifulSoup that are difficult to just split or partition effectively and consistently?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78263/discussion-between-spicyclubsauce-and-rob).